# Re-consuming nack'ed messages when all the other work is done

Tags: php, rabbitmq, php-amqplib

I'm implementing RabbitMQ to perform some image editing operations on another server. Though, from time to time the request may arrive on that server before the source image is synced to it - in which case I would like to pop the message back in the the queue and process it after all other operations have completed.

However, calling basic.nack with the resubmit bit set makes my queue re-receive that message immediately - ahead of any operations that operations that can actually complete.

Currently I feel like I'm forced to implement some logic that just re-submits the original message to the exchange, but I'd like to avoid that. Both because the same message may have been successfully processed on another server (with it's own queue), and because I expect this to be so much of a common pattern that there must be better way.

(oh, I'm using php-amqplib in both consumer and server code)

Thanks!

**Update**: I solved my problem using Dead Letter Exchange, as suggested by zaq178miami

My current solution:

- Declares a dead letter exchange `$dead_letter_exchange` on the original queue `$worker`
- Declares a recovery exchange `$recovery_exchange`
- Declares a queue `$dead_queue`, with a `x-message-ttl` of 5 seconds and `x-dead-letter-exchange` set to `$recovery_exchange`
- Binds `$dead_letter_queue` to `$dead_letter_exchange`
- And binds `$worker` to `$recovery_exchange`
- `$dead_letter_exchange` and `$recovery_exchange` are generated names, based on the exchange I'm consuming from and the value of `$worker`

Making every message that gets nack'ed return to the worker only on that specific queue (server) after five seconds for a retry. I may still want to apply some logic that throws the message away after `$n` retries.

I'm still open to better ideas ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have 'race condition' issue which is the cause of the problem. Maybe it is a good choice to delay message publishing or publish delayed messages to be sure that image synced to target machine or publish message when image arrives (which might be tricky) or just sync image on demand (when message consumed). You can even add some API to get source image, so you can scale your consumers horizontally without any pain any time. The idea is to make consumers atomic and undependable as much as it can be.

Back to original question, if it an option for you, try [Dead Letter Exchanges](http://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html) to move failed messages to separate queue. Mixing failed messages and valid without having definitive mechanism to detect re-published smells a bit (due to such reasons like potential cycling problem, management difficulties). But it really depends on your needs, messages rate and hardware, if some solution yields stable result and you are sure about it - just stick to it.

Note, if you are using php-amqplib you can start consuming messages from more than one queue at the same time, so you can consume messages from the main queue and postponed messages (but in such case you have to publish message to postponed queue delayed too to prevent it immediate consuming).

Usually delayed messages publishing done via per-message or per-queue ttl and extra queue with DLX set to the main working queue, or in your case to postponed messages queue.

Comment: Thank you ever so much. Of course, best practice would usually be to make sure the image exists before requesting an edit on it - but that doesn't quite fit my needs at the moment. But Dead Letter Exchange does.